# Using setTimeout with intervals less than 1

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I'm doing a lot of recursion in Javascript, and to keep the stack from overflowing, I've been using setTimeout.  Here's a quick theoretical example:

```
go(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        x++;
        go();
    },1);
}
```

I've also got a function logging `x` to the console every few seconds, but that isn't the concern.  What I'm seeing is that no matter what value I put in for the timeout, for which I've used 1 in the example, the script can only run 1000 times per second.  I'm doing recursion on the level of hundreds of millions, so this isn't fast enough.  When I set the timeout value to 0, or .1, or 1/10, I still only get approximately 1000 times per second.  I've tried using 32 and 64 bit browsers (Chrome and Firefox) to no avail.

How can I kick the speed up a notch?  Also, I'm relatively new at all of this, so it'd be awesome if the solution was a simple one.

Oh, forgot to mention: if I remove the setTimeout altogether, I overflow the stack every time.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I wonder why you are doing such heavy operations on client browser . Its better if you can find a way to run this on your server.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; if you're using setTimeout to keep the stack from overflowing, then you must not need recursion. So why do you need setTimeout? Going slower with recursion will only delay the overflow.

Comment: What you are doing doesn't seem right

Comment: There's a minimum timeout for setTimeout, but if you're targeting newish browsers you can use window.postMessage to do the same thing as fast as possible. I think MDN has an example. (Can't post a real answer now, on mobile.)

Comment: It might also be possible to use a custom event to do this, including on older browsers, but I haven't tried.

Comment: Thanks everybody, I've realized that it isn't an error with the actual code but with how I'm trying to use it.  I appreciate your help!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as "Too Localized". This may become the top hit in Google for "setTimeout with intervals less than 1s", but the discussion and answers have been more about the specifics of your code (localized), and there hasn't been focus on the question in the title (general).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried something like you did and found the solution! You don't need recursion and the function `setTimeout`, but all what you need is to use the `setInterval` function on the function you want by 1 interval repeatedly in `for` loop. For example if the for loop repeats itself 10 times, then 10 timers will execute the same function every 4 ms. The code will be executed repeatedly more and more quickly.

Your code should look like this for example:

```
function onload() {
   for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      setInterval(go, 1);
}
function go() {
   x++;
}
```

Comment: That's just a way to do slightly more work in the same manner, and a bad one. You would get the same result by simply doing the same thing several times in the function, with less overhead.

Answer (score 4):

Your solution doesn't lie in making your current code run, but to rethink the code.

I don't know how you are using recursion in your code, but clearly you are using it wrong.

For any reasonable use of recursion, you would be far from overflowing the stack. If you are making recursive calls to a level of hundreds of millions, that is at least a million times too much.

A common approach when using recursion is to divide the work in half for each level. That way you can handle all the items that you can fit in memory without going deeper than about 30 levels.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is single threaded, and setTimeout will put your operation at the end of the queue. Even if you reduce the delay, you still have to wait for the previous operations to complete before the one you added kicks in.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to make setTimeout wait less than 4 milliseconds.  That is how [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) is defined in the HTML standard (official spec [here](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/timers.html#timers)).  More likely your problem is with how your code is structured.  Show us the rest of your code, maybe we can help sort it out.

Comment: Based on your reference, the minimum is 4 ms, not 1 (see the notes)

Comment: Yes, it seems you are correct.  The function will let you specify a 1 ms delay, but internally this is raised to 4ms, according to the spec.  Fixed.

Comment: Right, you can even specify a 0 ms delay - this is often used by developers to move the execution to the end of the queue.

Comment: You don't have to include any time argument at all, and it will run after the minimum delay.

Comment: The spec states `Timers can be nested; after five such nested timers, however, the interval is forced to be at least four milliseconds.`